# How to use Entity Framework code-first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, console-application

I created some classes, and configured the connection string.

But still got an error:

> *Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Model compatibility cannot be
>   checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility 
>   can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.*

Comment: How did you create the database?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka the code-first feature can create database by code.

Comment: i fixed it 
by Run the ‘Enable-Migrations’ command in Package Manager Console.

Comment: @kevin you should post this as an answer to your question and mark it as correct so that other people reading it will be able to easily see your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it 
by Run the ‘Enable-Migrations’ command in Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the EF version you have, latest is 4.3.1.
2. You also need to configure a DbContext class. check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me if you are fine with deleting and recreating the database from scratch.

First, run the following commands from package manager console.

- sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0
- sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0

Next, delete the mdf and ldf files from the app_data folder of your project.

Here comes the critical part. Usually you will run update-database. If you do that the exception will still be thrown.

DO NOT Run update-database. INSTEAD directly run your project code. The EF will recreate the database.

These steps worked for me. Let me know if this helps you.